# SQL Server Replication Action if name is in use questions

Tags: sql-server, replication, merge-replication

When configuring a new Merge Replication, setting properties of all articles, I'm having a problem. In **Destination Object -> Action if name is in use**, I can select four different options. I'm trying to figure out what is each one. I'm not finding anything about it, they are:

- Keep existing object unchanged
- Drop existing object and create a new one
- Delete data. If article has a row filter, delete only data that matches the filter.
- Truncate all data in the existing object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The article property **Action if name is in use** correlates to the **@pre_creation_cmd** argument of [sp_addmergearticle](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174329.aspx):

> Specifies what the system is to do if the table exists at the
>   subscriber when applying the snapshot. pre_creation_cmd is
>   nvarchar(10), and can be one of the following values.
>
> **none** - If the table already exists at the Subscriber, no action is taken.
>
> **delete** - Issues a delete based on the WHERE clause in the subset filter.
>
> **drop** (default) - Drops the table before re-creating it. Required to support Microsoft SQL Server Compact Subscribers.
>
> **truncate** - Truncates the destination table.

Comment: I'm having this problem "Source:  Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 11.0
Number:  3726
Message: Could not drop object 'dbo.eqp_Equipment' because it is referenced by a FOREIGN KEY constraint."... If I select "truncate" will solve the problem? I will do it now, I'll post my result .

Comment: I couldn't change with sp_changemergearticle... It returns a error "Property 'pre_creation_command' of article 'myArticle' cannot be changed.". I'm recreating the Merge Replication... I'll post if it works or not :)

Comment: It didn't work... I still get the same error =(... actually it changed a little "
Cannot truncate table 'dbo.eqp_Equipment' because it is being referenced by a FOREIGN KEY constraint. (Source: MSSQLServer, Error number: 4712)"

Comment: What I find confusing and poorly documented (or perhaps I'm just stupid) is what exactly "none" refers to. Is this referring to schema related processes only? Or both schema and data processes?